# Additional fields sent to the Cart Controller in PrestaShop

Tags: php, controller, e-commerce, prestashop

Okay, so I was wondering how to send some custom data to the Cart Controller in PrestaShop (or to any controller, to be exact).

For example, some of my products have a "`size`" field. I want my `<form>` to include that field whenever there it is present in the product and send it to the Controller.

The problem is, how do I name that field so that the controller recognizes it?

Answer (score 1):

You can give any name which prestashop doesn't use for a particular context.

Here is how to do this.

1.Place your input field inside the buy_block form.

Example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="size" name="size" value="10" />
```

2.Then from CartController -> postProcess() method you can get it like this.

**$size = Tools::getValue('size');**

```
public function postProcess()
{
    // Update the cart ONLY if $this->cookies are available, in order to avoid ghost carts created by bots
    if ($this->context->cookie->exists() && !$this->errors && !($this->context->customer->isLogged() && !$this->isTokenValid()))
    {
        if (Tools::getIsset('add') || Tools::getIsset('update'))
            $this->processChangeProductInCart();
        elseif (Tools::getIsset('delete'))
            $this->processDeleteProductInCart();
        elseif (Tools::getIsset('changeAddressDelivery'))
            $this->processChangeProductAddressDelivery();
        elseif (Tools::getIsset('allowSeperatedPackage'))
            $this->processAllowSeperatedPackage();
        elseif (Tools::getIsset('duplicate'))
            $this->processDuplicateProduct();

        $size = Tools::getValue('size');
```

If you have to use this data to communicate with Database, this value will also be available at *updateQty* method of cart class.

```
public function updateQty($quantity, $id_product, $id_product_attribute = null, $id_customization = false,
    $operator = 'up', $id_address_delivery = 0, Shop $shop = null, $auto_add_cart_rule = true)
{
    if (!$shop)
        $shop = Context::getContext()->shop;

    if (Context::getContext()->customer->id)
    {

    $size = Tools::getValue('size');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you! I shouldn't edit the core controller, right? I think I should override it.

Comment: Yes. Override core files. Thank You! @peter

Comment: Okay :). I am testing this today, as soon as it works I am clicking your answer as accepted!